# ExtJS 5: How do I throw an error for repeating rows?

Tags: javascript, extjs, textfield, rows, repeat

I'm very new to ExtJS and JS. I was hoping someone could tell me if there is a way to check for repeated rows of the same name when entering a string into a textfield. Is there anything similar to "allowBlank: false" that could be used to check if the string already exists in a row? Or will I simply need to do validation through a series of loops?
Please tell me if anything is unclear in my question.

(also my first stack overflow post, so please let me know if there is anything I should have done differently with formatting/tagging)

Comment: I would listen to the `change` event on the field and search the text in the store, this will allow you to visually show if the text is valid. You can also use custom validators.

Comment: *"anything I should have done differently"* - A concise [fiddle](http://fiddle.sencha.com) / example generally garners a better response as it allows people to play around with minimal effort to replicate your problem (and without having to second guess your finer implementation details).